# How do I determine the height of a QTextDocument?

Tags: qt, qt4, qtextedit, qtextdocument

Given a specific width, I want to find out the height of a `QTextDocument`.  In other words, if the `QTextEdit` that contains the `QTextDocument` is *w* wide, what is its minimum height *h* in order to fully display the document without the need for scrollbars?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the width for the QTextDocument object to your desired with and then call the function `size().height()`, this should return the height required for the width you have to give it before.

Have a look at the `size()` function documentation of QTextDocument class.

Comment: Note: if your QTextDocument is inside of a QTextEdit showing html, and your goal is to find a height for the QTextEdit, it may be better to use QTextEdit.document().setPageSize( QSizeF( w, veryLargeH ) ), as opposed to QTextEdit.document().setTextWidth( w ) described above.

Comment: Does not work for me in PyQt5. `QTextDocument.size().height()` returns the number of rows of the text instead of pixels.

Comment: If the document has a QPlainTextDocumentLayout, it will use rows as unit of height instead of pixels.